# Socket.io socket.adapter.rooms returns null/empty array but data is present

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**UPDATE 1:**

I've got the problem down to this line here:

```
            var rooms = Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms);
```

Even though `socket.adapter.rooms` is not empty this returns an empty value.

The debug shows the following:

```
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting socket.rooms', socket.rooms );
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting socket.adapter.rooms', socket.adapter.rooms );
```

```
socket:connection/disconnecting socket.rooms Set { 'LBsXUemtWx9U8uV5AAAB', 'Test' }
socket:connection/disconnecting socket.adapter.rooms Map {
  'LBsXUemtWx9U8uV5AAAB' => Set { 'LBsXUemtWx9U8uV5AAAB' },
  'Test' => Set { 'LBsXUemtWx9U8uV5AAAB' } }
```

So the values are present but obviosly `Object.keys` does not like the JSON. I also tried `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` but that was the same.

**Original question:**

I'm cobbling together a basic chat app with rooms, which I will expand for another purpose.

Basic joining and chatting work fine, but I have an issue when the browser is closed or refreshed causing the Node server process to crash because in the `disconnect` event `socket.rooms` in empty.

Details: Node.js version v10.10.00 on Ubuntu 20.04, Socket v4.0.1

app.js is the main script the entry point script for the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const socket = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Render Index Class Page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`app.js:get/`);
    res.render('index');
})

//Render Start Class Page
app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`app.js:get/`);
    res.render('host_start');
})

//Render Join Class Page
app.get('/join', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`app.js:get/`);
    res.render('host_join');
})

//Get username and roomname from form and pass it to room
app.post('/room', (req, res) => {
    roomname = req.body.roomname;
    username = req.body.username;
    console.log(`User ${username} entering room ${roomname}`);
    res.redirect(`/room?username=${username}&roomname=${roomname}`);
})

//Rooms
app.get('/room', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(`app.js:get/room`);
    res.render('room');
})

//Start Server
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server Running on ${port}`);
})

const io = socket(server);
require('./utils/socket')(io);
```

The controller is socket.js which throws an error when the browser closes or is refreshed:

```
/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/utils/socket.js:62
            users[roomname].forEach((user, index) => {
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Socket.socket.on (/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/utils/socket.js:62:29)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.emitReserved (/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/node_modules/socket.io/dist/typed-events.js:56:22)
    at Socket._onclose (/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:333:14)
    at Client.onclose (/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/node_modules/socket.io/dist/client.js:245:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Socket.onClose (/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:348:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at WebSocket.onClose (/mnt/Workspace/nodejs/nexus/node_modules/engine.io/lib/transport.js:106:10)
root@ubun-nodejs#
```

socket.js is below. The error occurs in the `socket.on('disconnecting'` block. But when I print the content of `socket` to the log I can see the `socket.rooms` is present:

```
socket:connection/disconnecting: socket  Socket {
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     'joined-user': [Function],
     chat: [Function],
     typing: [Function],
     disconnecting: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  nsp:
   Namespace {
     _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     sockets:
      Map {
        'LxZu0PURyMuqS_DIAAAB' => [Circular],
        'hJqrx3Blp2q96KVIAAAD' => [Socket] },
     _fns: [],
     _ids: 0,
     server:
      Server {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _nsps: [Map],
        parentNsps: Map {},
        _path: '/socket.io',
        clientPathRegex:
         /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.min|\.msgpack\.min)?\.js(\.map)?$/,
        _connectTimeout: 45000,
        _serveClient: true,
        _parser: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {},
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        sockets: [Circular],
        opts: {},
        eio: [Server],
        httpServer: [Server],
        engine: [Server] },
     name: '/',
     adapter:
      Adapter {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        nsp: [Circular],
        rooms: [Map],
        sids: [Map],
        encoder: Encoder {} } },
  client:
   Client {
     sockets: Map { 'LxZu0PURyMuqS_DIAAAB' => [Circular] },
     nsps: Map { '/' => [Circular] },
     server:
      Server {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _nsps: [Map],
        parentNsps: Map {},
        _path: '/socket.io',
        clientPathRegex:
         /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.min|\.msgpack\.min)?\.js(\.map)?$/,
        _connectTimeout: 45000,
        _serveClient: true,
        _parser: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {},
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        sockets: [Namespace],
        opts: {},
        eio: [Server],
        httpServer: [Server],
        engine: [Server] },
     conn:
      Socket {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        id: '_XlX-xlIKIO_ryBNAAAA',
        server: [Server],
        upgrading: false,
        upgraded: true,
        readyState: 'closed',
        writeBuffer: [],
        packetsFn: [],
        sentCallbackFn: [],
        cleanupFn: [],
        request: [IncomingMessage],
        protocol: 4,
        remoteAddress: '::ffff:10.0.0.82',
        checkIntervalTimer: null,
        upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
        pingTimeoutTimer:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: -1,
           _idlePrev: null,
           _idleNext: null,
           _idleStart: 3731,
           _onTimeout: null,
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 104,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 103 },
        pingIntervalTimer:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: -1,
           _idlePrev: null,
           _idleNext: null,
           _idleStart: 3719,
           _onTimeout: null,
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 63,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 0 },
        transport: [WebSocket] },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     decoder: Decoder { _callbacks: {} },
     id: '_XlX-xlIKIO_ryBNAAAA',
     onclose: [Function: bound onclose],
     ondata: [Function: bound ondata],
     onerror: [Function: bound onerror],
     ondecoded: [Function: bound ondecoded],
     connectTimeout: undefined },
  data: {},
  acks: Map {},
  fns: [],
  flags: {},
  server:
   Server {
     _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _nsps: Map { '/' => [Namespace] },
     parentNsps: Map {},
     _path: '/socket.io',
     clientPathRegex:
      /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.min|\.msgpack\.min)?\.js(\.map)?$/,
     _connectTimeout: 45000,
     _serveClient: true,
     _parser:
      { protocol: 5,
        PacketType: [Object],
        Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
        Decoder: [Function: Decoder] },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     sockets:
      Namespace {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        sockets: [Map],
        _fns: [],
        _ids: 0,
        server: [Circular],
        name: '/',
        adapter: [Adapter] },
     opts: {},
     eio:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        opts: [Object],
        ws: [WebSocketServer] },
     httpServer:
      Server {
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 5,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5 },
     engine:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        opts: [Object],
        ws: [WebSocketServer] } },
  adapter:
   Adapter {
     _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     nsp:
      Namespace {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        sockets: [Map],
        _fns: [],
        _ids: 0,
        server: [Server],
        name: '/',
        adapter: [Circular] },
     rooms:
      Map {
        'LxZu0PURyMuqS_DIAAAB' => [Set],
        'Test' => [Set],
        'hJqrx3Blp2q96KVIAAAD' => [Set] },
     sids:
      Map {
        'LxZu0PURyMuqS_DIAAAB' => [Set],
        'hJqrx3Blp2q96KVIAAAD' => [Set] },
     encoder: Encoder {} },
  id: 'LxZu0PURyMuqS_DIAAAB',
  connected: true,
  disconnected: false,
  handshake:
   { headers:
      { host: '10.0.0.44:3000',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        accept: '*/*',
        'user-agent':
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36',
        referer:
         'http://10.0.0.44:3000/room?username=Mr%20Chipps&roomname=Test',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9' },
     time: 'Sun Apr 25 2021 16:13:57 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)',
     address: '::ffff:10.0.0.82',
     xdomain: false,
     secure: false,
     issued: 1619363637442,
     url: '/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Na9c2rA',
     query:
      [Object: null prototype] { EIO: '4', transport: 'polling', t: 'Na9c2rA' },
     auth: {} } }
```

socket.js:

```
const {getUsers, users} = require('./getUsers');

//Socket connection
function socket(io) {
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {

        socket.on('joined-user', (data) =>{
            console.log('socket:connection/joined-user ' + data.username + ' room ' + data.roomname);
            //Storing users connected in a room in memory
            var user = {};
            user[socket.id] = data.username;
            if(users[data.roomname]){
                users[data.roomname].push(user);
            }
            else{
                users[data.roomname] = [user];
            }
            
            //Joining the Socket Room
            socket.join(data.roomname);
    
            //Emitting New Username to Clients
            io.to(data.roomname).emit('joined-user', {username: data.username});
    
            //Send online users array
            io.to(data.roomname).emit('online-users', getUsers(users[data.roomname]));
            
        });
    
        //Emitting messages to Clients
        socket.on('chat', (data) =>{
            console.log('socket:connection/chat ' + data.username + ' room ' + data.roomname + ': ' + data.message);
            io.to(data.roomname).emit('chat', {username: data.username, message: data.message});
        });
    
        //Broadcasting the user who is typing
        socket.on('typing', (data) => {
            console.log('socket:connection/typing ' + data.username );
            socket.broadcast.to(data.roomname).emit('typing', data.username);
        });
    
        //Remove user from memory when they disconnect
//        socket.on('disconnecting', ()=>{
        socket.on('disconnecting', (data)=>{
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting' );
            var rooms = Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms);
//            var socketId = rooms[0];
//            var roomname = rooms[1];
            var socketId = data.socketid;
            var roomname = data.roomname;
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting: socket ', socket );
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting: rooms ', rooms );
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting: users ', users );
            console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting: data ', data );
            //console.log('socket:connection/disconnecting: clients ', clients );
            
            users[roomname].forEach((user, index) => {  // !!! Errors here with undefined !!!
                if(user[socketId]){
                    users[roomname].splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
    
            //Send online users array
            io.to(roomname).emit('online-users', getUsers(users[roomname]));
        })
    })
}

module.exports = socket;
```

getUsers.js:

```
//Store connected Users
var users = {};

//Funtion to get users online in a room
function getUsers(arr){
    console.log('getUsers ');
    onlineUsers = [];
    arr.forEach((onlineUser) => {
        onlineUsers.push(Object.values(onlineUser)[0])
    });
    return onlineUsers;
}

module.exports = {getUsers, users};
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer was to replace this:

```
            var rooms = Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms);
```

With:

```
            var rooms = Array.from(socket.rooms);
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.adapter.rooms returns you a map if you have set an adapter for your sockets. You can check if room exists like this in map no need to manually check anything.

```
socket.adapter.rooms.has(room)
```